# Changing image via passing img src through state not working

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a picture I've imported as the default value for the image: prop in state, It shows but it doesnt change when I try to change the value via the component in another component

Here is the child component of a webpage component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import YellCubePlant from '../imgs/CPC Yellow Cube Planter.jpg'
import AubSkinnyPlant1 from '../imgs/CPC Aubergine SKINNY PILLAR Planter (P).jpg'
import AubSkinnyPlant2 from '../imgs/CPC Aubergine SKINNY PILLAR Planter.png'
import OliveSkinnyVase from '../imgs/CPC Olive Green SKINNY VASE Planter.png'

class Item extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            image : YellCubePlant,
        }

    }
  render() {
    return (

       <div className="item">
           Item Name
           <img src={this.state.image} alt="placeholder"></img>
       </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Item;
```

and here is the parent component which this is nested and I try to change the states image value. As seen with the `<Item image={AubSkinnyPlant1}/>`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Item from '../item';
import YellCubePlant from '../../imgs/CPC Yellow Cube Planter.jpg'
import AubSkinnyPlant1 from '../../imgs/CPC Aubergine SKINNY PILLAR Planter (P).jpg'
import AubSkinnyPlant2 from '../../imgs/CPC Aubergine SKINNY PILLAR Planter.png'
import OliveSkinnyVase from '../../imgs/CPC Olive Green SKINNY VASE Planter.png'

class Collection extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div className="container-fluid"> 

       <h1>
         The Collection
       </h1>

       <div className="colltext">
          Our collection of products within the Landscape exhibition.
       </div>
       <div>

       </div>

       <Item image={AubSkinnyPlant1}/>
       <Item />
       <Item />
       <Item />
       <Item />
       <Item />
       <Item />
       <Item />

     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Collection;
```

IT just shows the image which is the default in state from my Item component, why is this?

Comment: You should set your src for the image from the image prop passed from the Parent  to the Child (Item) . Currently you set the default state and use that , but you do not change state  so it is always the default. However , if you use the props passed to the child from the parent , that should achieve what you want , so there is no need to use state in the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use the `image` from the component state, it will not be changed when given an `image` prop from the parent component.

You could just use the prop given by the parent component and use `YellCubePlant` as a default value instead.

```
class Item extends Component {
  render() {
    const { image = YellCubePlant } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="item">
        Item Name
        <img src={image} alt="placeholder" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are not updating the state `image` of `Item` component properly, as you are initializing it with some image it will show that image only

but you want to render image from props so, I think you should convert `Item` component into functional component like below,

1 using functional component.

```
// default image ( YellCubePlant )
export default function ({ src = YellCubePlant, ...props }) {
  return (
    <div {...props}>
      <img src={src} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

or

you can do it by updating the state using the props like below,

2 component using life cycle methods

```
export default class Item extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      src: YellCubePlant // default image.
    }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.src !== nextProps.src) {
      return ({ src: nextProps.src })
    }

    return null
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={this.state.src} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Note: I recommend 1st option if you simply rendering the `src` or if you are doing some operation using life cycle method then 2nd will be more helpful, choice is yours.

best of luck